# How to forbid stopping windows service

Tags: windows

well, look at msdn about windows service.
i have a myservice, i think my service is not be stopped.i look at other service, if u click stop service by taskmgr, there is a window show u havnt right to control it.i want to do it seem this, how to do ? anybody talking about ?

seem windows service code

```
static void ServiceHandler(DWORD dwCommand)

void ServiceMain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
```

thank u everyone.

i have looked BuildExplicitAccessWithName api, but:

```
BuildExplicitAccessWithName(&ea, TEXT("Administrator"),
0,
SET_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE);
```

its not reach my effect.

Comment: You can't prevent an administrator from stopping a service. But you can prevent a limited user account from doing so. Stopping a service requires the `SERVICE_STOP` privilege.

Comment: thank u for answer .im not agree with u, as i look at other product. refuse service stopping when i click menu. so i think how to do by programming.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent *administrators* from being able to stop services?

Comment: thank u for ur answer, its my work content. a company about net security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a service wishes to accept stop requests, it must set the `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` bit in the `dwControlsAccepted` field when calling [`SetServiceStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241(v=vs.85).aspx).

If a service does *not* wish to accept stop requests, all it has to do is to not set that bit.  You can even change whether or not you accept stop requests in real-time, if you wish to do so.  For example, you might accept stop requests while the service is idle, but refuse them when it is busy.

Comment: u r right, this setting can reach my thinking. i found it.  but now, user stll can kill process and make service to be stopped. i search some code about it. ntdll. reflect api . RtlSetProcessIsCritical, u can see

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43405/Protecting-Your-Process-with-RtlSetProcessIsCriti

Comment: but this program is only valid in winxp. win7 havnt effect.

Comment: Well, of course an administrator can kill the process.  The administrator is in charge.  Your software isn't entitled to override the administrator's wishes.

Comment: thank u for ur answer, i'll keep searching, i found alot of answers. thanks

Comment: IIRC, there is a special API for security software, but you have to sign up with Microsoft to get access to it.